# how to remove automatic adding '?q=' in htaccess when accessing subfolders

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder in the root called 'php', and when I type a url like this in my site:

```
http://example.com/php
```

it turns like this:

```
http://example.com/php/?q=php
```

but if the folder doesn't exist, it does not add the '?q='. I've tried adding:

```
Options -Indexes
```

but still happens. my site uses 'q=' to access different pages and I don't want the users to know that there's folder/s existing if the url adds a '?q='. how can I remove or disable that? I'm still new to htaccess thanks!
Here is my current htaccess:

```
#
# Apache/PHP/msys settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(inc|profile|functions|pg|module|test|po|api|sh|ini|json|.*sql|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ ?q=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 403 /example/error404
ErrorDocument 404 /example/error404
```

Comment: Did you try removing the directive that adds it?

Comment: _"`http://example.com/php` it turns like this: `http://example.com/php/?q=php`"_ - and the purpose of that redundancy would be what exactly in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe my site uses the 'q=' to access the other php. like this:
example.com/error404 - displays the error404 page. if there's still something like 'q=' displaying in the url. it do nothing and not cool in the eyes

Comment: _"but if the folder doesn't exist"_ - what folder?

Comment: @CBroe only the folder/s existing that adds the '?q=' in the url. for example, I don't have a folder called 'php2' in the root and typed this in url `example.com/php2`, it will not add the '?q=' in the url and still look like this `example.com/php2`. But when i type `example.com/php` it becomes like this `example.com/php/?q=php` because I have a folder called php in the root folder.

Comment: Add `-MultiViews` to `Options`. And btw., I think you can not use the Options directive multiple times, you need to list all the options at once after the directive name.

Comment: @CBroe it didn't work

Comment: Then add a RewriteCond before the rule, that checks if the requested URI is not an existing folder.

Comment: @CBroe I'm still new to htaccess so I still don't know how to do it correctly

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`